# Simple form with CherryPy

Tags: python, forms, submit, cherrypy

I'd want to add a simple form that show a single text area.

When user submit the form I need to call a function that check the validity of the data and elaborate it.

I have added the form in the page in this way:

```
<td><form method = "get" action = "getnote"> <input type="text" name="note"/> <button type="submit"><img src="/img/validate.jpg" width="20" height="20" /></button></form></td>
```

With getnote I want to call a function getnote(note) that check validity and save it in a db.

Then I have :

```
class HelloWorld(object):
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    return "Hello world!"


@cherrypy.expose
def getnote(self, note):
    #check and save
getnote.exposed = True

@cherrypy.expose
def HomeP(self):

    Session = sessionmaker()
    session = Session(bind=engine)


    template = loader.load('index.html')
    title = "Home page"
    ctx = Context(title=title)
    return template.generate(ctx).render('html', doctype='html')
```

then in the localhost/HomeP there is the form and is showed correctly, when I fill the form and submit it, the browser show me an error of path "HomeP/getnote/" missing. But I want to call getnote as a function and not as a page!

I have followed this tutorial but maybe there is something that I've missed:
http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-4-submit-this-form

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn the basics of the technology you deal with. And the basics of StackOverlow to ask good questions, so they are comprehensible and useful to others.

You have relative form action, `action='getnote'`, which tells a browser to appended it to the current pathname. This is why you get form submitted to `/HomeP/getnote/`. Use absolute action instead, `action='/getnote'`.

Even though your "*But I want to call getnote as a function and not as a page!*" sounds like a nonsense, I guess I have an idea where to guide you. Learn about [AJAX](https://google.com/search?q=ajax) and eventually you will be able to send a form in background.

Comment: I'm still learning! I'm still following the tutorial in the link posted. So, I cannot understand why if I copy and paste the example it work, if I launch my program it isn't.

Comment: @user2174050 It is because copy-pasting without understanding the subject is a bad practice. It has nothing to do with CherryPy. It is how an HTML form submits to a relative ``action`` URL. In the tutorial, the form is at ``/`` (``index`` method), and in this case ``action=generate`` leads to `/generate` action URL. In your case, the form is at ``/HomeP``, and ``action=getnote`` leads to ``/HomeP/getnote``.